# SQL: count # rows between Step A and Step B, in process flow?

Tags: mysql

So I'm new to SQL and trying to learn the syntax of this.  I know theorietically what I need to do, but do not know the specifics.

GOAL:  find # of rows between two steps in a process flow for a given Lot#.
so I need to query the inventory data base to find current step for the lot, then feed that into a query against the flow plan, and count the rows between current step and end step.

```
select lotID, step#
from currentInventory
where lotID = "LOTA"
```

--> this outputs a single row, the current step#

```
select Step#
from FlowPlan
order by Step#
```

--> this outputs the entire flow plan, for example step#:  AA1000 to AA9555.

I need to find the # of steps between AA6378 and currentstep.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

does this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM currentInventory 
WHERE `lotID` = "LOTA"
and `step#` <= (SELECT `step#` 
                from FlowPlan 
                ORDER BY `step#` ASC LIMIT 1);
```

```

Comment: I'm adjusting to my DB's specific names now.  Quick question:  you have single quote around lotID and double quote around the lotA value.  Is this correct?

Comment: @surfer349 you backticks to denote column names in mysql safetly and values are surrounded by either single quotes or doubles quotes. single quotes are used more frequently, but double quotes suffice.